# Flask database works in development but not in production with uWSGI

Tags: python, nginx, sqlite, flask, uwsgi

I have a flask app that makes use of a sqlite3 database. When I run the application with in development with debug on, it works exactly as expected.

When running the application with uWSGI, uWSGI Emperor and Nginx, the app runs as expected until I hit a button that causes interaction with the database.

The error is an: Internal Server Error

I am unable to debug the situation because flask does not allow debug mode in production.

I assume the problem is that the application is looking for the static database file in the wrong directory. Where might I place the database so it is found?

Not sure what information to post besides this. Will update if needed.

**EDIT: Problem was solved by giving the full path of the database. Is there a way to get a dynamic full path to a file in Flask?**

Comment: Doesn't it log to stderr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the relative path to the file, you could use:

```
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt")
```

to retrieve the files absolute path.

Comment: But is this the "proper" way to do it in Flask?

Comment: This is the pythonic way to retrieve an absolute path for a file. As you said, Flask is waiting for the absolute path to the file, and this is how it's done.